# How can I publish to Facebook from an Android Service?

Tags: android, facebook, android-service, publish

I want to do a service that publish on Facebook  at a determinated time. The problem is that I only know how to publish using the `UILifeCycleHelper`, and that class needs an Android Activity, not an Android service. Is there another way to publish on FB, that can be used in a service?

Answer (score 0):

FB SDK is open source under Apache terms you can modify it to work with service.

SDK works by making HTTP requests to FB service. 
You can log this requests and generate them your self.

These URLs have access_token field. You can get access_token from regular FB SDK and generate HTTP requests in service manually by adding access_token

Comment: If you like my answer you may mark it as response and I will get some points as reward